# What is the difference between a json resource & resource collection? in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-eloquent-resource

Can someone explain the difference between a ResourceCollection and JsonResource?

In Laravel 6 docs you can generate 2 different types of resources... ResourceCollection and JsonResource.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#resource-responses

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class ShopCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource collection into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

vs ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Shop extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you are converting a single model to json, that is a json resource, when you are converting a collection of model to json, that is resource collection.

simply If you are returning a collection of resources or a paginated response that is a collection.

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#generating-resources)

> to generating resources that transform individual models, you may
>   generate resources that are responsible for transforming collections
>   of models. This allows your response to include links and other meta
>   information that is relevant to an entire collection of a given
>   resource.

Comment: @MiguelStevens  if you want to make some modifications based on request parameter, you can use that, if you would like to know more, go through my questions, I have posted a code regarding resource with query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel Resource** will transform and format your data before sending it to the client. (Single record)

**Laravel Collection** also does the same, but it holds multiple data records instead of a single record, and also, with the collection, we have access to functions like `map`, `filter`, and `pluck` to manipulate data

- `UserDetailsResource::make($user);` (Single esource)
- `new UserResource($user);` (Single resource)
- `UserDetailsResource::collection($users);` => If collection

> **Note:** In the latest PHP, we can add a return type to the function ex `destroy(): void`; if you use `UserDetailsResource::collection($users);` the return type will be `:AnonymousResourceCollection`. else `:UserDetailsResource`